# How to catch a iframe loading error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this iframe:

```
<iframe id="website-overlay" src="link" onload="OverlayMostraCustomContenuto()"></iframe>
```

but this function is loaded even if there is an error on the loading, such as:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4cQsoz4mFA&feature=share does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

Is there a way to know if the iframe is loaded correctly or not? I guess yes, if Firebug can catch it.

Answer (score 7):

My "solution" doesn't detect all iframe errors, but it does "detect" the one mentioned in the question on sites that you have no control over.

I have onload="load()" in the iframe which calls the load() event. Only problem is that this load event gets called even if the load failed. I've tried using the onerror="error()" event but it never gets called.

It's a bit hacky I know, but I haven't been able to find anything better so as a workaround for this I do the following:

When the iframe is requested, I set the iframeRequestTime in miliseconds somewhere on the page. When the load() event is called, I get the loadTime. Then I find the difference between loadTime and requestTime. If the request was blocked, the response will be fast so the difference will be small. I've set it so that if the difference is under 1000ms, I remove the iframe and open the URL in a new window. I figure that unless the website is really small, or unless you have an incredibly fast internet connection, most sites wont fully load in under 1000ms.

```
function LoadIFrame(url) {
    // Create & display iframe
    var iframe = '<iframe src="' + url + '" onload="load()"></iframe>';
    $('#iframeHolder').append(iframe);

    // Time
    var time = new Date().getTime();
    $('#iframeHolder').attr('data-time', time);
}

function load() {
    var requestTime = $('#iframeHolder').attr('data-time');
    var loadTime = new Date().getTime();
    var difference = loadTime - requestTime;
    if (difference < 1000) {
        var url = $('#iframeHolder iframe').attr('src');
        window.open(url, '_blank');
        $('#iframeHolder').empty()
    }
}
```

Normally I wouldn't have posted such a hacky fix but this question has been here for a while now with no answers. Obviously this solution is not a perfect fix but it suits the needs of my site just fine. Any suggestions|will be welcomed.